# Custom validation is not working inside forms.py

Tags: django, python-3.x

I want to validate my email field like: if email contains `[gmail.com,outlook.com,yahoo.com]` then I want to raise validation Error. But it's not working, I don't know what i am doing wrong. plz help me

### views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import View
from access.utils import is_valid
from access.mixin import HttpResponseMixin
import json
from access.forms import Employer_Form
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

@method_decorator(csrf_exempt,name = 'dispatch')
class Emp_Registration_view(View,HttpResponseMixin):
  def post (self,request,*args,**kwargs):
    data = request.body
    json_data = is_valid(data)
    if not json_data:
        return self.render_http_response(json.dumps({'msg':'Please send valid json only'}),status=400)
    emp_data = json.loads(data)
    form= Employer_Form(emp_data)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save(commit=True)
        return self.render_http_response(json.dumps({'msg':'Registered Successfully'}))
    if form.errors:
        return self.render_http_response(json.dumps(form.errors),status=400)
```

### forms.py

```
from access.models import Employer_Registration
from django import forms

class Employer_Form(forms.ModelForm):
  def clean_email(self):
    email = self.cleaned_data['emp_email']
    email_lists = ['gmail.com','yahoo.com','outlook.com','hotmail.com']
    data = emp_email.split('@')
    if data in email_lists:
        raise forms.ValidationError("email is not valid")
    return email

  class Meta:
    model = Employer_Registration
    fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: still you need to fix the split @Ipd to get it working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method should be named `clean_emp_email`,  because the field is named `emp_email`. Otherwise it won't be called.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are splitting on `@` so if you split `example@gmail.com` it will be `[example , gmail.com]` and that you are comparing in this line exactly

```
if [example , gmail.com] in email_lists
```

so it is not found I suggest you to do you can omit splitting and find in substring as

```
for i in email_lists:
    if i in self.cleaned_data['emp_email']:
       raise forms.ValidationError("email is not valid")
```

After @Alexandr Tatarinov answer you should also call the `clean_field_name` or simply `clean`